# in Backbone, why can't I trigger the 'reset' events when I do fetch()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

That's may be some simple code, but I don't know the reason:

```
initialize : function(){
    this.offSaleCollection = new Collection.ProductsCollection();
    this.offSaleCollection.url = '/products';

    this.offSaleCollection.on('reset', this.render, this);

    this.offSaleCollection.fetch();
    // this.offSaleCollection.reset();  if I do this, the event can be triggered.

    },

    render: function(){
        console.log(this.offSaleCollection);
        $('#off-sale-tab .badge').html(this.offSaleCollection.length);
    }
```

That's why I can't trigger the 'reset', so that I can't get the render function.

Comment: I think, I might be wrong, but change "reset" to the event name "sync". Like I said, could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the backbone's implementation of the fetch method:

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
  if (options.parse === void 0) options.parse = true;
  var success = options.success;
  var collection = this;
  options.success = function(resp) {
    var method = options.reset ? 'reset' : 'set';
    collection[method](resp, options);
    if (success) success(collection, resp, options);
    collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
  };
  wrapError(this, options);
  return this.sync('read', this, options);
}
```

So, the reset method is called if you pass `reset: true` in your options. However, even then the event may not be triggered, because:

```
reset: function(models, options) {
  options || (options = {});
  for (var i = 0, l = this.models.length; i < l; i++) {
    this._removeReference(this.models[i]);
  }
  options.previousModels = this.models;
  this._reset();
  models = this.add(models, _.extend({silent: true}, options));
  if (!options.silent) this.trigger('reset', this, options);
  return models;
}
```

If `options.silent: true` then the `reset` event is not fired.

So, I guess that you should use `sync`.

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but that is code for Backbone's `fetch` method for `Backbone.Model`. The code for a [Backbone.Collection](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-104) is slightly different. Depending on whether `{reset:true}` is passed to `fetch` determines if a `sync` or `reset` event is triggered first (if at all for a `reset` event).